# JavaScript puzzle to reimplement Array.prototype.slice not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is not for a job interview, don't worry :)

I am curious as to why these two functions return differently:

```
var redundantSlice1 = function() {
    return arguments[0].slice(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1).join())
};

var redundantSlice2 = function() {
    return arguments[0].slice(1,2)
};

redundantSlice1([1,2,3], 1, 2) // [1,2,3]

redundantSlice2([1,2,3], 1, 2) // [2]
```

`redundantSlice2` returns what I expect, but the `1,2` are hardcoded, this is what I am trying to avoid.

Why does the first function have what I expect to be `1,2` as `undefined`?

Comment: `.join` returns a string. So the first example is equivalent to `arr.slice("1,2")`. That's very different from `arr.slice(1, 2)`. I'm not sure how `.slice` treats invalid arguments (apparently it treats it like `0` or nothing was passed).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found. I had the same results passing `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: May as well make that the answer :)

Comment: you need to look at `function.apply` - but as slice only ever takes 0, 1 or 2 arguments, I'd define your wrapper function as `function(array, begin, end)` then simply return `[].slice.call(array, begin, end)` - that's just as much a *re-implementation* as you've written

Comment: There are more constraints to the problem that I didn't want to give away as to not cheat, but @FelixKling answered my initial question. It's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `redundantSlice1`, `.join( )` converts the arguments into a string with `,` as the delimiter by default. So with your sample, the statement

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ).slice( 1 ).join( )
```

Is actually `"1,2"` not `[ 1, 2 ]` like you're expecting.

In addition to this, you're only passing one argument to `.slice( )`. In order to match the behavior of `redundantSlice2`, you must use [`.apply( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```
var redundantSlice1 = function() {
    var firstArg = arguments[ 0 ];

    return Array.prototype.slice.apply(
        firstArg,
        Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 )
    );
};
```

Comment: This could probably also just be done with `arguments[0].slice(arguments[1], arguments[2])`.

Comment: what if `arguments[0]` is "array-like"?

Comment: @FelixKling Yep, I'm just being consistent with the OP's approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this so you can pass an array or an array-like object and get the same result

```
var redundantSlice1 = function(array, begin, end) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(array, begin, end)
};
```

this will work with 1, 2 or 3 arguments passed in exactly like Array.slice works

If you insist on slicing the arguments and have no "formal parameters" to the function

```
var redundantSlice1 = function() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments[0], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
};
```